# Affectiva's unity sdk makes android application crashed when Application.LoadLevel function is called

Tags: affdex-sdk

I've been developing an academic application for emotion recognition using Affectiva's affdex SDK for Unity. 
But when I use affectiva CameraInput object and want to load a level, my game crashs on android.

Here is my code:

```
    private void finishGame()
{

    var cam = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>().GetComponent<CameraInput>();
    Destroy(cam);

    var det = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>().GetComponent<CameraInput>().GetComponent<Detector>();
    Destroy(det);

    StartCoroutine("LoadMyLevel");

}

    IEnumerator LoadMyLevel()
{
    yield return null;
    Application.LoadLevelAsync("mainMenuScen");


}
```

this problem asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109342/aafdex-sdk-unity3d-crash-on-scene-transition-only-on-android), but doesn't really help me.